# Bouncing Tube equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

What is the equation to find the bouncing height of a cylindrical tube when the flat surface is falling on the floor under earth's gravity? I know the mass, drop height and material properties of the cylindrical tube.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the [coefficient of restitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution) $\epsilon$ between the tube and the floor then the bounce height $h$ is related to the drop height $H$ by

$$h = \epsilon^2 H$$

If you don’t know the coefficient of restitution but you have an actual tube then you can determine $\epsilon$ by experiment.

If you don’t know the coefficient of restitution and you want to determine it from first principles from the material properties (Young’s modulus, Poisson ratio, density etc.) of the tube and the floor then I think this will be quite difficult. One method of predicting the coefficient of restitution from first principles is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution#Predicting_from_material_properties), although it only applies to colliding spheres.

Comment: I don’t know the coefficient of restitution.
Actually I am trying to calculate the impact force due to freefall. As I know the KE due to fall, I need the impact distance to calculate the force (1/2 mv²/d).
If this is difficult to calculate theoretically, any equation to calculate impact time to use Newtons second law to calculate the Impact force.

Comment: @TechGuy Energy is average force times distance, so to find the average force of impact you need to divide the kinetic energy of the tube at impact by the distance its centre of mass travels before its KE is zero.  This distance will depend on how much the tube deforms during impact - the bigger the deformation, the smaller the average force (this is the principle behind crumple zones in cars).

Comment: As the theoretical calculation of deformation during impact is difficult, can I use newtons second law for the force calculation where the impact time is required to calculate the acceleration (v/t)? is there any method to calculate the impact time using material properties?

Comment: @TechGuy Impact time, average force, average acceleration and deformation are all interconnected and all depend in a complex way on the material properties of what is being bounced. If they didn’t then tennis balls, snooker balls, basket balls, foam balls and bowling balls would all bounce in the same way.